# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [2] Access denied

Tags: api, soap, magento-1.9

I Just created custom SOAP api module in Magento 1.9. and I just try to access the product list from outside of magento. and it throws:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [2] Access denied. in /opt/lampp/htdocs/products.php:4 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/products.php(4): SoapClient->__call('customapiProduc...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/products.php on line 4"

My products.php Code is:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/mage1/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
$sessionid = $client->login('admin', 'productdata');
$result= $client->customapiProductList($sessionid);
var_dump($result);
```